# Laravel redirect function doesn't seem to work on logout

Tags: laravel

I want the user to be able to logout only when he is logged in.
After he/she is logged out, he should be redirected back to the login page. Here are my codes:

```
class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function logout(Request $request)
    {
        Auth::logout();
        $request->session()->invalidate();
        $request->session()->regenerateToken();

        return redirect(route('login'));
    }
}
```

And here are my routes

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return redirect(route('admin.dashboard'));
})->middleware('auth');


Route::get('/login',[LoginController::class,'index'])->name('login');
Route::post('/login',[LoginController::class,'authenticate']);

Route::prefix('admin')->name('admin.')->group(function(){
    Route::post('/logout',[UserController::class,'logout'])->middleware('auth')->name('logout');

    Route::get('/register-customer',[CustomerController::class,'index'])
        ->middleware('auth')
        ->name('register-customer');

    Route::post('/register-customer',[CustomerController::class,'store'])
            ->middleware('access.authorize');

    Route::get('/dashboard',[DashboardController::class,'index'])->name('dashboard');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out. I don't know, but there seems to be something fishy with "UserController" name that when I changed it to something else, it now works.